# Is it possible to test word document like a snapshot test in Java, Spring, JS or whatever else?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, kotlin, jestjs

I have a service that generated a word document with some variables. I want to check is it the same as example ? Now I test it manually but it very time consuming process. Is it possible to automate it ? I know that in jest I can make a snapshot testing of my frontend but not found any similar for my task

Comment: Why do you have java, spring and kotlin tags in this post?

Comment: because i want to write my own microservice and it is not matter what program language to use. I write on all of them

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a JS library to generate this word document, which means that should not test third-party libraries you can only [mock it](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api) and make sure that it's being called with the correct parameters by using

- [`.toHaveBeenCalledWith`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledwitharg1-arg2-)
- [`.toHaveBeenCalledTimes`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber)

Or that it throws when something wrong happens:

- [`.toThrow`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror)

And in case you need more than to unit-test it, I suggest that you use a library that parses and reads the word document for you and compares the results.

Comment: No i want to test word template expected with word template actual. It is like a snapshot testing but with word or pdf

Comment: In this case there is no native method from Jest to do this snapshot testing, however you may find third-party libraries like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-pdf-snapshot) or build your own